# Issue with AdLdap2 at Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, adldap

I receiving an error when i am trying to use LDAP with Laravel 5.5

```
"Use of undefined constant LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION - assumed 'LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION'"
```

However, i have enabled the PHP extension of LDAP

```
$ php --ini |grep ldap

/etc/php.d/ldap.ini,
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/php.d/ldap.ini
; Enable ldap extension module
extension=ldap.so
```

and php information

```
$ php --info |grep ldap
/etc/php.d/ldap.ini,
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
ldap
ldap.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

I am using

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 30 2017 10:30:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: yes, the issue is fixed. I used new Instance, changed web server, installed libraries and compiled PHP from scratch, -with--ldap --enable-ldap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved.

I installed the LDAP libraries and recompiled the PHP with LDAP from scratch.

./configure --other-extensions --with-ldap --enable-ldap

Answer (score 0):

For ldap on a homestead box (laravel vagrant machine) or other Ubuntu with php-fpm and nginx...

```
apt-get install php5.6-ldap
apt-get install php7.0-ldap
apt-get install php7.1-ldap
apt-get install php7.2-ldap
```

this installs and sets up everything you need.

Make sure you `shutdown -h now` and restart your box for php-fpm and nginx to see the updates.